# How do I add large amount of columns(5000~1000 columns) to a initial DataFrame in a very less time?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to conduct some kind of stress test on the pyspark pipeline that I have created and want to test if the columns of the input dataframe(that is retrieved from Hive) are increased to 2x ,5x times then how will the pipeline work?

I have tried to create duplicate columns of the numerical columns already present in the dataframe using a for loop:

```
for i in range(5000):
    df = df.withcolumn('abc_'+i,df.col1)
```

But this is taking a lot of time.
Is there some efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

withColumn method could have some overhead, try using `functions` and `select`, such as:

```
>>> dup_cols = [F.col('col_1').alias("abc_{}".format(i)) for i in range(1,10)]
>>> df_duplicated = df.select(df.columns + dup_cols)
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id_9: string (nullable = true)
```

Anyway, since this kind of operations are lazily evaluated in Spark, I don't know if a large number of duplicated columns could test effectively against an actual large number of differente columns. This difference could be event bigger if original data are also saved in a columnar-optimized format such as parquet.

Comment: I thought foldLeft was more of an issue than withColumn

Comment: Still didn't have time to test differences, but I think it depends on the dataset. Sadly I still don't have both time and knowledge to dive deep into this :-(

Comment: But you provide an answer. If you were my dr. I would be worried.

Comment: sorry no time for joking. I experienced by myself and read on SO about some issues on withColumn() method, so I suggested to try using directly select() method. if you have time please test and benchmark yourself different approaches and share the results, thanks.